# HTTP Headers on Protected Downloads

Tags: php, header, download

So I'm using this [article](http://ardamis.com/2009/06/26/protecting-multiple-downloads-using-unique-urls/#comment-1828) to generate and protect some download links on my website

The problem I'm having is the script works, just not with huge files. For example, a 1GB file downloads perfectly, whilst a 7GB one doesn't.

Someone in the comments mentioned large downloads might cause this.

My headers looks like this at the moment:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($fakefilename) . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($realfilename));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($realfilename);
exit;
```

And this [guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#86554) is suggesting they should look more like this:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));    
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");             
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
flush(); // this doesn't really matter.

$fp = fopen($file, "r"); 
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536); 
    flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
}  
fclose($fp);
```

For the life of me, I can't get this to work. Anyone here that is familar with HTTP headers and while large but not small files can't be downloaded?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "doesn't download" mean exactly? What are you getting, what aren't you getting? Any errors in any log files?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sorry, I've amended some code.

Comment: @deceze So, the smaller 1GB file downloads perfectly. The larger file just downloads the $fakefilename file which is like 1KB. The fake file is some sort of placeholder file, not sure why its there tbh.

Comment: What does the 1KB file contain?

Comment: @Pekka웃 It's just a zipped .pdf I think. This is how it's explained in the article: Set the variable $fakefilename to anything – this is what the visitor’s file will be named when the download is initiated.

Comment: does the downloaders target file system support files over 4GB....

Comment: @Orangepill How would I find that out?

Comment: Find out the filesystem / os type and research

Comment: And what does `header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));` return for files > 2GB?

Comment: @Orangepill I'm super confused. Could you point me in the right direction on how to get hold on this information?

Comment: You should first look into the 1KB file and see what's in it. There very may well be an error message there

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Think it might be overflowing?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller It seems any file > 2GB just downloads the fake file and doesn't initiate the 7GB download, even though the download link is valid.

Comment: [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) is of file system types and what the max file size supported on it.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Here is a download link to the 1KB file. http://s169017.gridserver.com//download.php?id=a81c04da1d1d

Comment: @Orangepill The thing is, I can download the raw 7GB file if I punch in the raw path into my web address bar.

Comment: So far I've gotten 52 MB of the 1KB File :)

Comment: echo out PHP_INT_MAX on the server... I think @dev-null-dweller might be on to something... on 32 bit system the max integer for php is about what the content length of a 2GB file would be (unsigned 32 bit integer)

Comment: @Orangepill Ok, my bad. That fake file is 7MB. If you're getting 52MB, I have to believe that might be downloading properly. Why wouldn't it be working on my machine?

Comment: If the results of the  filesize call is overflowing then it will end up getting set to filesize%PHP_INT_MAX bytes, your browser might just be killing the download after it determines that the content-length header is a lie

Comment: @realph php on 32bit systems can't handle files bigger than 2GB properly. While accessing it via raw url, transfer is handled only by webserver, not php interpreter. To handle big files look into `X-SendFile` (lighttpd / apache mod) od ` X-Accel-Redirect` (nginx)

Comment: @Orangepill PHP_INT_MAX: 2147483647

Comment: You can try to drop the content-length header entirely, the only thing you will loose in that case is you won't get a progress bar that makes sense

Comment: I'll bet if you divide 2147483647 into the total size of the file the remainder will be the size of the file that actually got downloaded

Comment: @Orangepill Yeah, dropping the content-length header gives me a XX.XMB of ? in Safari. Any other way around this?

Comment: upgrade to a 64bit host...

Comment: or possibly fish the file size as a string from a filesystem call... like ls or something.

Comment: @Orangepill On the horn to MediaTemple at the moment. What would fishing the file size require?

Comment: on a linux machine you should be able to `exec("stat -c %s ".escapeshellarg($filename));`

Comment: Ok, totally confused. Is there an "easier" way or solution around this? Two protected files that I need multiple unique URLs for? Btw, I really appreciate all the help @Orangepill!

Comment: All you should have to do is replace `header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));` with `header("Content-Length: " . exec("stat -c %s ".escapeshellarg($filename)) );`

Comment: I posted this as the answer, accept it if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by the `filesize` call overflowing the systems PHP_MAX_INT which yields a length less then that of the entire file. (Which is about 2GB on a 32bit machine)

Only browsers that trust the content-length header over the size of the file itself appear to be afflicted.

Solution is to change

```
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
```

to

```
header("Content-Length: " . exec("stat -c %s ".escapeshellarg($filename)));
```

Comment: Dude!!!! You are a superstar. How the hell did you work that one out. Tremendous. Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: Would you happen to know of any reasons why some downloads are ending prematurely?

Comment: same one file always failing or is it more intermittent?

Comment: Both files actually? Works fine on my machine, but my girlfriend's machine seems to be ending part way through the download.

Comment: what kind of machine does she have. browser operating system etc

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. iMac. I have a Mac Pro. Both using Safari and Mtn Lion.

Comment: Don't know anything specific that would cause that based on the client, Mountain lion I believe can support files up to 2 terabytes. If you are able to access it on the same network without fail then to troubleshoot the issue I would attempt the download hosted else where (I believe the google drive has 10GB on the free account).